# What is the use of below mentioned query and i need to display the values as we need

Tags: sql, sorting, hive

I am having an below SQL query:

```
SELECT emp_name AS ID,emp_name as label from emptable
WHERE 1=1
<#if query?? && query?trim!="">
AND (UPPER(empname) LIKE UPPER('${query}%'))
</#if>
ORDER BY id
```

what exactly   tag doing here

I have datas in empname as "Eagle","Mark","Nigil","Eagle_22","MARK","MARK_22","MARK_22","Nigil","Adran"

i want to display the MARK_22 as first and MARK as 2 value..
How we can achieve that

Comment: That looks like a very dodgy use of some templating engine to generate Dynamic SQL.

Comment: There is no need to use `UPPER` here (SQL string comparison is case-insensitive by default) and it will wreck your query's SARGability (or whatever Hive's equivalent concept is).